# Is Jonah's prophecy five or six words long?

Tags: hebrew, language

It appears to me that most scholars commenting on the length of Jonah's prophecy in Jonah 3:4 say that it is five words long in Hebrew. The Hebrew וְ isn't counted as a word in this context, and that reality suggests to me that it wouldn't be counted in most other contexts. But וְ itself is a word. It is the "and" in English translations of this verse. In the KJV Bible, Jonah 3:4 has eight words where "and" is considered one of those words. The Hebrew וְ is not a contraction, and it appears to function (at least in this context) just like the English "and."

It seems to me that the reason for not counting וְ as a word in Jonah 3:4 could be summarized as, "Just because." Is it simply that in the Hebrew mind, וְ isn't a word that's important enough to be counted? If so, would the Hebrew mind also wonder why the English mind would count "and?" If that's the case, perhaps I can truthfully say that the prophecy in Jonah 3:4 consists of six words from my perspective but that the native Hebrew speaker would count only five of those words.

Comment: From [Biblehub Interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/jonah/3-4.htm) it looks to me like an adverb, a participle and three nouns (one with a _waw_). Not sure why the number of words (five or six) would have any relevance to anything important, myself. Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and functioning of the site.

Comment: When I saw the association of "and" with וְ and made an incorrect assumption based on the layout of different study resources, I began to wonder why different sources said the prophecy was five words long, instead of six. Perhaps, I should've considered the Hebrew text apart from any other information and formatting. Regardless, I'm glad I wondered and asked about it because I've learned more than I would have otherwise. I agree with your implication that the number of words isn't very important, but my uncertainty made it important to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hebrew text of Jonah 3:4 is

### וַיָּ֤חֶל יֹונָה֙ לָבֹ֣וא בָעִ֔יר מַהֲלַ֖ךְ יֹ֣ום אֶחָ֑ד וַיִּקְרָא֙ וַיֹּאמַ֔ר עֹ֚וד אַרְבָּעִ֣ים יֹ֔ום וְנִֽינְוֵ֖ה נֶהְפָּֽכֶת׃

The last five words of which are:

> עֹ֚וד אַרְבָּעִ֣ים יֹ֔ום וְנִֽינְוֵ֖ה נֶהְפָּֽכֶת׃ = yet forty days &
> Nineveh shall be overthrown

Thus, the Hebrew is indeed just five words long.

Now, Hebrew is not English: conjunctions, many prepositions do not form separate words.  Further, some words in Hebrew are not translated at all such as the direct object marker.  Some single verbs and nouns must be translated by a short phrase in English, etc.  Hebrew is a Semitic language and English is a Germanic language - unrelated to each other.

in the case of the waw consecutive, this is not always translated, especially in a list of nouns and so cannot be counted as a separate word.  there is a similar situation with the lambda and a few other preopositions.

In short, Jonah's prophecy is indeed just five Hebrew words long.